# Finding the Equation of a Line Using Horizontal Tangents and Derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I'm stuck on this one problem for my homework and it involves using given horizontal tangents to find an equation for a line using a generic polynomial.
For the sake of following the rules of the forums, I'm changing up what the horizontal tangents are because I want to understand the process for solving it, not just getting the answer.

The horizontal tangents that I am given in the actual problem are at (-4,4) and (2,-2), but instead of using those, please use (1,1) and (-5,-5).

$$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

The derivative of this results in $f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c$. I know that to find the horizontal tangents you factor the derivative so that you can find the values for $x = 0$, but I don't understand how that can be done without having values for the constants. I don't know whether or not I am supposed to use the horizontal tangent points to determine the constants, or if I'm supposed to factor the derivative.

**Update**

I think that upon setting $f'(x) = 0$ that I can say that $c = 3ax^2 + 2bx$, but I don't know what else can be done from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal tangents occur where $f'(x)=0$, so for $x=1$ and $x=-5$ as you stated $f'$ vanishes. Since $f'$ is a quadratic function we have
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=3a(x+5)(x-1)\qquad\qquad\text{where }a\text{ is constant}\\
&=3ax^2+12ax-15a
\end{align}
Then
$$2b=12a\;\implies\;b=6a\qquad\text{and}\qquad c=-15a$$
So,
$$f(x)=ax^3+6ax^2-15ax+d$$
On the other hand, $$f(1)=1\qquad\implies\qquad a+6a-15a+d=1\quad\iff\quad -8a+d=1$$
$$f(-5)=-5\qquad\implies\qquad -125a+150a+75a+d=-5\quad\iff\quad 100a+d=-5$$

Now, by solving the system of two linear equations you will know  $f$.

Comment: I completely forgot that it was possible to set it up so that the constants are equal to each other. And I also didn't even think to substitute in the values for x. It's been a while since I've had to do derivatives. I also forgot that since you have to factor to find the values for x that make $f'(x) = 0$ that whenever you don't have $f'(x)$ factored, you can just substitute the factor with the values for x. I feel really stupid right now. Especially since this makes total sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the derivative tells you the slope of the tangent line at a particular value of x.  You know two values of x for which the tangent line is horizontal.  What is the slope of a horizontal line?